# How should I add my rule file to Suricata?

Tags: security, suricata, ids

I was looking into suricata and I could not understand something about configuration file. As in the documentation we need to add our rule file to the suricata.yaml like this:

```
default-rule-path: /usr/local/etc/suricata/rules
rule-files:
         - suricata.rules
         - /path/to/local.rules
```

Should we need write the directory of the local.rules(sample file) ? Or we just keep it as /path/...

Which one is the correct usage?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine.  A rule file without a leading / will be loaded relative to the default-rule-path.  I will often have a section that looks like:

```
default-rule-path: /var/lib/suricata/rules
rules-files:
  - suricata.rules
  - /etc/suricata/rules/local.rules
```

Where `suricata.rules` is the output of `suricata-update`.  And `local.rules` is just a rule file I manually update.